# How to detect if an tif image has layers with python preferably with pil

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, photoshop, tiff

Im trying to find out if file (tif) has multiple layers. Ive looked though the pil documentation but couldn't seen anything that points to it. Has anyone got any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean by layers?  Can you link to an example of such an tif?

Comment: I dont have any examples with me sorry, they are the same as photoshop layers if that helps?

Comment: ok.  My understanding is that you are working with files that are the photoshop extension to tiff, not strait tiff files.  You should probably edit your question to include the words 'photoshop' someplace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a shot in the dark, but according to [this pdf](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/tiff/TIFFphotoshop.pdf) layers are defined in tag 37724.  You might try seeing of that tag exists

```
im = PIL.Image.open(fname)
try:
    im.tag[37724]
    layers = True
except:
    layers = False
```

(can't actually test this as I don't have any of these files)