# Get number of layers in tif image using python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have [the tif image](https://img.3dyuriki.com/files/5_layers.tif) with 5 layers (not color channels but layers).
How can I get the number of layers in this tif file using python?

I tried PIL.Image im.**n_frames** and cv2.**imreadmulti** they all show that image has only one layer.

Comment: hi, might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477292/how-to-detect-if-an-tif-image-has-layers-with-python-preferably-with-pil

Comment: Thank you. I tried it. But I didn't find a way to show the **number** of layers

Comment: Here is the link for that missing pdf [TIFFPhotoshop](https://www.alternatiff.com/resources/TIFFphotoshop.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layers in these kind of TIFF files are hidden in the Adobe Photoshop specific ImageResources (#34377) and ImageSourceData (#37724) TIFF tags.

Use the [psdtags](https://pypi.org/project/psdtags/) library to parse these tags, e.g.:

```
from psdtags import TiffImageSourceData

isd = TiffImageSourceData.fromtiff('5_layers.tif')
number_layers = len(isd.layers)
for layer in isd.layers:
    layer.name
    for channel in layer.channels:
        ch = channel.data  # a numpy array
```

Run `python -m psdtags 5_layers.tif` to preview the layer information in the TIFF file.

Comment: psdtags officially works only with python >=3.8. And I have the limitation: I have to use Python 3.7. But with a few dirty hacks, it now works with 3.7.2. I've used **pip install --ignore-requires-python psdtags** and then delete all positional-only parameters (/) from psdtags.py + installed a few missing libraries